Does the Team ID on Apple Developer Portal need to match the one on Keychain?
I was trying to solve the error "Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code" that occurs when I try to archive and publish my app.  A suggested solution is to fix the Bundle ID.  Now I think they match on Xcode and the Developer Portal. But the CodeSign error still persists.  I realized the Team IDs on the Portal and my Mac local keychain do not match.

The number on KeyChain, is that's a Team ID. (clueless self learner here)
If yes, do they need to match?
Any suggestion for the CodeSign error?

Sorry if these questions are obvious or stupid.  Thanks so much for any advice.
